# What happened to the “‑est” and “‑eth” verb suffixes in English?

Tags: verbs, archaicisms

What happened to them, and how were they once used? Straining my mind to sound archaic, I came up with the following:

> Dost thou **thinkest** thou can escape thy sins?

and

> **Bringeth** me mine armor and favorite sword.

I’d like to use these suffixes intelligently, so my questions are:
how are *‑est* and *‑eth* properly appellated in conjugations, and 
when and why did they disappear?

Comment: These examples are incorrect.  The first should be "dost thou think...", because you've already conjugated *do*, and the second should be *bring* because that is the imperative form. *Bringeth* would be the 3rd person indicative form ("he bringeth").

Comment: Indeed. Ugh, seeing fake English like that makes me want to cry…

Comment: The correct versions would be “Dost thou think thou canst escape thy sins?” and “Bring me my armor and my favorite sword.”

Comment: Nice to see we have plenty of people here capable of correcting medieval grammar. I also find it exceptionally irritating when people get these mock versions so wrong. But at least now I can tolerate people saying **Y** instead of **Th** in *Ye Olde Tea-Shoppe*, for example. So there is hope my 'word-rage' can be managed without excessive bloodshed.

Comment: @Kosmonaut: Personally I'd have expected *mine* rather than *my*. For no reason I can articulate - unless it's just that *mine* sounds even more archaic, and I can only think in terms of exaggerating the mockery.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Yes, you are right; it would have been *mine* because the following word (*armor*) begins with a vowel.

Comment: Um, wouldn't *Thinkest thou that thou canst escape..* be perfectly KJV-compliant?

Comment: @TimLymington: I'm sure your construction would have been valid - but as Kosmonaut said, OP's inflection is wrong because 2nd person singular was *already conjugated* by **dost**.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Verb paradigm in King James English for *think*

```
   Singular             Plural
   --------------------------
1  (I)    think         (we)   think
2  (thou) thinkest      (you)  think
3  (he)   thinketh      (they) think

Imperative: think
Infinitive: (to) think
```

These unfamiliar suffixes are applied in the same context that the *-s* suffix is applied in Modern English; for example:

> - He thinks.
> - Thou thinkest.
>
>   ---
> - He shall go. (no *-s* suffix on *go*)
> - Thou shalt go. (irregular verb form for *shall*; but again, no suffix on *go*)

During the Early Modern English period, the 2nd person singular suffix disappeared and the *-th* suffix in the third person was replaced by another suffix, *-s*, which spread from dialects in the northern parts of the country.  Other conjugations, such as *-e* in the first person singular from Middle English, had already been lost.

This sort of change is known as [paradigm leveling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphological_leveling). There is no particular reason *per se* that this kind of change happens, but it is not uncommon in the languages of the world.

Comment: What about that song by The Ark, "Calleth you, Cometh I", do you remember it? If "-eth" is the third person, what's going on here? I was just wondering :D

Comment: @Alenanno: They probably just did it wrong (either intentionally or unintentionally, I don't know).

Comment: To expand on this, morphological leveling isn't a random phenomenon. It can be difficult to track the precise reasons for a specific change, but we can conjecture that it might be similar to issues like verb agreement in Modern English ("they/you is"). This one is likely the result of AAVE; the ancestors of modern African-Americans, not being native speakers of English, largely had difficulty grasping things like verb agreement which may have been radically different in their native language. Language is mimetic, so these little peculiarities spread beyond just one cultural group.

Comment: Re: 'Calleth you, Cometh I.'  In some dialects it, mostly of Middle English, it was common to use '-th' in the first person (I calleth).  In Old English, and indeed Middle English, '-ath' was a common plural suffix; thus we get 'you calleth'.  Hopefully that clarifies things.

Answer (score 17):

It's basically a feature of being a Germanic language. In German, the second person takes -st, e.g., "Ich bin, du bist, Ich kenne, du kennst" (I am, you are, I know, you know).

The old English forms follow the same pattern, as Kosmonaut shows above. This is the easiest way to spot "fake Elizabethan" language in books and movies. "Wouldst thou?" is fine, "wouldst I?" don't fly.

Comment: sein is a poor example as quite irregular, but kennen is good

Answer (score 3):

*-Est* was dropped when the uniquely singular "thee/thou/thy" fell out of use. *-Eth* was eventually replaced by *-s* or *-es;* the point being that language changes over time and tends to move toward simpler forms.

Answer (score 3):

In English, as in other languages, we employ "First Person" (the one speaking), "Second Person" (the one being spoken to), and "Third Person" (the one being spoken about). There is singular (*I speak*) and plural (*we speak*).

Using French as an example, I can say *tu parles* to my friends (Second Person Singular), but to show respect I would say *vous parlez*, whether to one of you with whom I'm not familiar or to more than one of you. So *vous* is the plural as well as the formal form of *tu*. The same in English. *You* is the plural of *thou.*

Other languages use *she* and the Third Person to show respect, since such words as *grace* and *majesty* are feminine (*Sie* in German and *Lei* in Italian). Still others use a word formed from *Your Grace* to show respect (*Vuestra Merced* in Spanish becomes *Usted* after *Vuestra* being abbreviated as "Vst" which became "Ust" and combined with "-ed" from *merced*. The Portuguese *você* has a similar construction coming from *vossa mercê*, or *Your Grace*.) In some Spanish-speaking countries, the formal *Usted* (which, keep in mind, takes the Third Person form) replaced the Second Person *tú*.

This is what happened in English: the formal use of *you*, even in the singular sense, replaced *thou* almost everywhere except, for example, among the Amish: *thou speakest* and *you speak*. The same for their object pronouns *thee* and *ye* which were replaced by the subject pronoun *you*. So that's what happened to *thou* and its suffix "-est."

As for the ending "-(e)th," that was replaced over time by "-(e)s": *he maketh* becomes *he makes*.

Comment: -eth didn't get replaced randomly. The northern dialects had -es even in the early Middle English period. It spread southward and replaced -eth during the later Middle English and Early Modern English period.