# "Geteth the tax"?

Tags: orthography

I was driving today, and I saw this billboard:

> The tax man cometh.  Geteth the health insurance.

Is this spelling correct? I'm not used to -eth, so I am not sure. Should it be "getteth"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What happened to the "-est" and "-eth" verb suffixes in English? How were they once used?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22459/what-happened-to-the-est-and-eth-verb-suffixes-in-english-how-were-they-on)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If we are looking for historical correctness, then this phrase isn't even correct, because "get the health insurance" is an imperative sentence and the imperative form of *get* was *get* in Early Modern English.  So the accurate sentence would be "get the health insurance".

However, if you want to know whether the form for the 3rd person singular is *geteth* or *getteth*, then we run into another problem; spelling was not completely standardized when these suffixes were used, so there is probably record of both used.  However, one of the major standards-setters in the English language was the King James version of the Bible, published in 1611.  In my corpus of the King James bible, the spelling *getteth* is used 9 times, and *forgetteth* is used 4 times.  No single-t spelling is used.  Further, in the 2nd person singular forms, we see *begettest* (2x) and *forgettest* (2x), and no single-t versions.

So, this might be the closest thing to an authoritative answer to how this word should be spelled.

Comment: +1 for giving me my first-ever chance on ELU to upvote a "pedantic" answer! I really get ticked off by people (even in jest) emulating medieval forms so badly!

Answer (score 5):

It is unlikely that the person who wrote this was aware of the existence of an actual word "get(t)eth".  I certainly wasn't.  The first half of the phrase is a play on "The Iceman Cometh", a play by Eugene O'Neill.   I suspect the second is purely intended humourously.

Comment: "The tax man cometh" is a common phrase, generally used to refer to the inevitably of taxes. I've heard that it was originally a play on words of the O'Neill play, though I haven't done the research to prove that.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you're correct. [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/getteth) gives *getteth* as an archaic third-person singular present simple form of get. But [Google NGrams](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=geteth,getteth&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) show, that *geteth* did have a bit of usage in early 19-th century. The difference is overwhelming though, so I'd say there was a typo on the billboard you saw.

[image]

Comment: The spelling may be OK, but as others have said, the grammar isn't.

Comment: @Colin Fine Yep, haven't noticed it until saw the other answers

Answer (score 2):

Even in archaic English, the imperative of 'Get' is - 'Get', ('Get thee to a nunnery', Hamlet). 'Getteth' (or occasionally 'geteth': see Philoto's answer) would be third person singular.  Sadly, copywriters for billboards rarely check a 16th century dictionary (or even this site), before approving an amusing, eye-catching line.

Answer (score 1):

As well as the spelling, it seems a very strange construction.  Obviously it is meant to be comically archaic language, but I think it would read better as

> The tax man cometh.  Getteth thou the tax.

Comment: _'... meant to be comically archaic language ...'_ In this instance, or in other uses of the word / this form? If the latter, then all I can really say is that you must find the KJV Bible hilarious.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment - In this instance, rather than in genuine historical usage or even artistic anachronistic usage.  Saying that, the KJV can be hilarious at times - all the stuff about bowels moving with compassion!

Comment: Learnest thou thy archaic conjugations. The conjugation of get goeth: *thou gettest* and not *thou getteth*.

Comment: @Peter Shor - I knew there was something wrong.  However, I think @TimLymington is correct.  While _gettest_ may be the present, _get_ is the imperative.