# How do you conjugate Early Modern English verbs (other than present tense)?

Tags: verbs, tenses, suffixes, early-modern-english, conjugation

I was wondering how one might conjugate verbs in early modern English in various tenses. I am aware of the fact that for second person and third person singular specifically, the verb endings are *-est* and *-eth* respectively, but once you move away from simple present tense, it seems to get a bit trickier.

I recall reading somewhere that if you want to make a verb past simple, you add *did* between the noun and the verb. For example,

> He ?*dideth walk* to the store.

As opposed to the modern English,

> He *walked* to the store.

And as opposed to how I might say it:

> He ?*walkedeth* to the store.

Unfortunately, I haven’t learned quite as much of English as others may, but I know enough to suspect that “He dideth walk to the store” might be a different tense entirely from “He walkedeth to the store”, at least in modern English.

I am an aspiring and amateur writer, and there is a character that speaks entirely in Early Modern English, and so the answer to this would be quite helpful.

Comment: Welcome to English.SE! And that's a well-constructed question (although we don't really need the apologies and thanks); have some rep. It *might* be off-topic. My experience is that it would be "He did walk to the store" rather than **dideth* but I'm sure there are other more knowledgeable people...

Comment: "Walked", or "walk'd", is perfectly correct Early Modern English. "Walked" occurs in [*Mucedorus*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mucedorus); "walk'd", in [*Venus and Adonis*](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Venus_and_Adonis). Not \*"walkedeth", however; unlike *-est*, *-eth* is only used in the present tense (it's equivalent to Present-Day English *-s*).

Comment: It is an interesting question, but not, I suspect, one that lends itself to answering here. ‘The Oxford History of English’ has 10 pages on ‘-eth’ and ‘-es’ verb endings in Tudor English alone and the picture is clouded by the number of dialects spoken during the early modern period.

Comment: I made some edits to your question and I removed some information in order to focus the readers on what you are asking rather than on you.  You might be interested in the [Writers.SE] site as well.  We have weekly chats on Tuesdays.

Comment: @BarrieEngland You mean -eth and -est, not -es, right?

Comment: @tchrist: No, I meant it as posted, although I should have shown them as '(e)th' and '(e)s'.

Comment: @BarrieEngland Ok, I see what you mean now. Interesting as the full history is, I bet the OP would be satisfied with a set of present (and past, maybe) indicative conjugations in all 6 of I/thou/he/we/ye/they forms, like those one might expect to find in the KJV or Shakespeare (yes, I know these varied). You'd have to do a "regular" verb plus *be, have, do, go* and maybe another sample irregular or two to get the feel of it.  This isn't something you can just look up on Wikipedia, oddly enough.

Comment: **Who told thee that thou wast naked?** (King James Bible)

Comment: @GEdgar Indeed. The OED entry on *be* has many, many pages on historical forms, and mentions how for a time *thou wast* and *thou wert* alternated in usage for a 2nd-person singular past indicative: “The modern analogical *wast* has displaced the etymological *were* (with grammatical ablaut) chiefly under the influence of Tindale and the Bible; the intermediate *wert* (Shakspere’s form) prevailed in literature during the 17th and 18th c., and has been used by many 19th century writers.”

Comment: From my bookmarks: [_"Why Does Everyone Talk So Funny?"_](http://english.basd.k12.wi.us/mocarski/shakespeare/language.html). There's also a section dedicated to verbs on [WP's EME page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_Modern_English#Verbs) - the references might be useful.

Comment: *When thou wast young, thou girdest thyself, and walkedst whither thou wouldest...* (KJV) Perhaps you can be more specific about which period your character is from, since the era spans nearly two centuries.

Comment: Related: [What happened to the “-est” and “-eth” verb suffixes in English? How were they once used?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22459/)

Answer (score 36):

It is unfortunately common for writers to attempt dialogue in Early Modern English, even though they do not know this language. This typically results in a [panoply of howlers](http://garethrees.org/2009/01/22/super-paper-mario/#section-5): *-th* and *-st* added randomly to verbs, *thee* used as the subject of sentences and *thou* as the object, *mine* used before consonants, and vocabulary used in anachronistic senses.

There's really no substitute for reading widely in the language. It's easy to get hold of texts from the period via [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/), [Google Books](http://books.google.com/), the [Internet Archive](http://archive.org/) and so on (editions often modernize spelling but usually leave grammar and vocabulary alone). The *Historical Thesaurus of the Oxford English Dictionary* is a useful tool for finding vocabulary that's appropriate to a particular historical period, or if your library lacks this work, then try [Google Advanced Book Search](http://books.google.com/advanced_book_search) by date.

It will pay dividends if you immerse yourself in the language even as you attempt to learn its rules, and so I recommend James Greenwood's [*Royal English Grammar*](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=m29XAAAAYAAJ) of 1737, which says (page 60):

> In *Engliſh* there is no Change at all made of the Verbs; except in
>
> The Second Perſon Singular of the Preſent Tenſe, and in the Second Perſon Singular of the Preter Tenſe, which Perſons are diſtinguiſhed by the Addition of *eſt*; as, *thou burneſt*, *thou readeſt*, *thou burned'ſt*, *thou loved'ſt*. So likewiſe
>
> In the Third Perſon of the Preſent Tenſe, an Alteration is made by adding the ending *eth*, or *s*, (or *es* if the Pronunciation requires it;) as, *he burneth* or *burns*, *he readeth* or *reads*. In all the other Perſons the Word is the ſame; as, *I burn*, *we burn*, *ye burn*, *they burn*. So, *I burned*, *he burned*, *we burned*, *ye burned*, *they burned*, &c.
>
> If the Preſent Tenſe ends in *e*, the *ſt* is added inſtead of *eſt*, in the Second Perſon, and *th* inſtead of *eth* in the Third Perſon; as, *I love*, *thou loveſt*, *he loveth*.

Both your examples contain solecisms:

> *He dideth walk to the store.

Use "he did walk". [For example: 1687  *The Compleat Office of the Holy Week* 249  *Noe* was a a juſt and perfect man in his generations: He did walk with God.]

Also, *store* meaning "a place where merchandise is kept for sale" is, according to the *OED*, an American usage first attested in 1731, so may not be appropriate for your period. Try *shop* instead.

> *He walkedeth to the store.

Use "he walked". [For example: 1608  J. Donne *ΒΙΑΘΑΝΑΤΟΣ* (1648) 169  expoſing himſelfe to certaine danger when he walked upon the water.]

Comment: (Greenwood is too late to be truly *Early* Modern English himself, but I couldn't find anything suitable from any earlier. He does cover EME grammar; and getting used to the style and orthography will be helpful to the original poster before seeking out earlier works.)

Comment: A very good book, really a chrestomathy with many annotated reading selections and extremely clear discussion, is Manfred Görlach's 1991 [_An Introduction to Early Modern English_](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZENf7A82WpQC&pg=PA164&lpg=PA164&dq=manfred+görlach+introduction+to+early+modern+english)

Answer (score -2):

***advice for the -est, -'st, -'th, and the -eth suffixes: conjugation ***

*Verb Conjugation of **to have***

1. I have, I had
2. Thou hast, thou hadst/didst have
3. He/she/it hath/has, he/she/it had
4. We have, we had
5. Ye/you have, ye/you had
6. They have, they had

You have to look at the context of the verb in this case. Here is an example modified from an unpublished book that I've been writing.

> Thou **hast** *followed* me from Marteus's house. He **hath** *told* me to help thee to finish this quest.

Using the conjugations for *to have* as much as you can ***WILL*** make your life ***SO MUCH EASIER!***

*Verb conjugations of **to be***

1. I am, I was
2. Thou art, thou wert
3. He/she/it is, he/she/it was
4. We are, we were
5. Ye/you are, ye/you were
6. They are, they were

There is only one area of conjugation where it is different from our everyday speech: the second person singular. "Thou art" is the present tense, and "thou wert" is the past.

I am not going to do another full-length conjugation list. this time I am only going to show you the areas where the words change a little bit. These conjugations are for the verb ***to do***.

- Thou dost, thou didst

**Remember that most of the conjugations are the same. Try to use the verbs *to have* and *to be* as much as you can.**

Comment: Welcome to ELU. This answer appears comprehensive, but would benefit from corroboration as it contains several errors. He hath told me to help ***thee***. *Do* begets *dost* not *dust*. And *did'th* doesn't exist either. Do read Gareth Rees's answer.