# What is the etymology or history of "Your" for addressing a noble?

Tags: meaning, etymology, history, forms-of-address

There are several ways of noble addressing, such as:

- Third person - female (Her)
- Third person - male (His)
- Second person (Your)

*e.g : Your Highness*

But, what are the meanings behind that?
Why it seems differ from **your** as in *"pack **your** own things!"*

English is not my native, but addressing noble such as *"My King"* is more reasonable to me.

Comment: When you speak to a noble instead of addressing them directly, you address a positive attribute of them as a form of deference. You talk about their stature or grace or title rather than the person. It creates distance which reinforces the distance in social status.

Comment: This seems to go back longer than English. E.g. French has "monsiuer", which appears to be a contraction of "mon sieur", which I presume is related to English "my sir".

Comment: Much farther. Nobles require flattery and [there are many ways to do it.](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/119175/15299)