# Why is the Elizabethan English incorrect in this quote?

Tags: grammar, archaicisms, early-modern-english, conjugation, verb-forms

I saw a [Geico commercial](http://www.ispot.tv/ad/7fZX/geico-oldest-trick-in-book) with Elizabethan verb forms that bothered me because they were being misused:

> Trick Number 1. **Lookest** over there!
>   *Servant looks*
>   Haha! **Madest thou** look!
>   So **endest** the trick!

How would a native speaker of Elizabethan English have phrased these sentences? Specifically, what verb forms would they have used if this scene were authentic?

Comment: The problem isn't only with the verbs. After they're fixed, "thou" should become "thee".

Comment: @AndreasBlass, that's one of the things I was going to post in my answer.

Comment: "Proofreading questions are off-topic unless a specific source of concern in the text is clearly identified." The questioner said "the problem is with the verbs." That sounds pretty specific to me.

Comment: It's not a proofreading question; it's a grammar exercise. And I was planning to answer it myself.

Comment: @phenry: read the two comments right above yours. Not specific and *the OP knows it*. Anyway, this is not even a question in the first place, but a riddle, and as such off-topic. I picked a softer close reason, though, as I indeed always try to do. More often than not, it serves me a fat lot of good.

Comment: @Brian Of course it is wrong, in strikingly obvious ways, but it is not its goal or purpose to be right. Just like there is not a single Hollywood movie, no matter how high its budget, in which the evil Russians actually speak anything remotely resembling actual Russian. It's not supposed to be right. It's merely supposed to be alien enough. Same for Middle English and Early Modern English. (Note how Old English is too alien for anybody to even try.)

Comment: I have edited my question; can it now be answered?

Comment: @RegDwigнt - If the close reason does not fit the question, then you shouldn't use it--and if there are no close reasons that fit, then maybe the question shouldn't be closed at all. I don't see a "because it's a riddle" close reason anywhere, and I can't find any prohibition on riddles in the help center. Indeed, this question seems likely to lead to informative answers about verb inflections in early modern English that I, for one, would be interested to read.

Comment: @phenry I appreciate the edit. That puts it into the realm of the intellectual.

Comment: I'm not [quite] old enough to remember what we used to say back then, but I probably wouldn't argue with ***"Look thou yonder!" ... "Ha! I didst make thee to look!"  ... Thus endeth the trick***

Comment: @Fumble, close, but not quite. "Look over thither", "Haha! I made thee look," and "so endeth the trick" would have worked just fine.

Comment: @Brian J. Fink: Are you sure? I thought "thence" had *always* implied ***from** there*, not ***to/towards** there*. And surely archaically it was always *he maketh me **to** lie down*, using an "infinitive" form. I did just check ***so*** in OED though (I thought the "in that way" sense was more recent, but you're quite right).

Comment: @FumbleFingers as soon as I posted the comment, I edited it to read "thither."

Comment: @Brian: Ah, right! Yeah, that sounds better. But although obviously I don't know what was "idiomatic" back then, *look [over] yonder* seems to have been around the block. Maybe they did say *look thither*, but it's not so "familiar" to my modern ear.

Comment: @Fumble, if you want to be picky, yes, perhaps "to" was used with infinitives, and maybe they didn't say "over", but I simply wanted to point out the **glaring** errors, such as global use of 2nd person indicative (or interrogative for the second verb) for forms ranging from imperative to 3rd person indicative.

Comment: @Brian: I'm not with you. How is [*"Look thou upon us, O Lord, according to thy Mercie"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22look+thou+upon+us%2C+O+Lord%2C+according%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) any different to *"Look thou yonder"*? In 1708 that was "ancient and scarce", according to the preface, and it looks like the same "imperative" form to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I think the cumbersome wording found in the KJV and Duay-Reims bibles comes from the fact that educated men translated them; therefore, the English would have been more Shakespearean in nature&mdash;more refined and proper. Perhaps "thou" in an imperatival form is technically correct, but I'm not certain about the use of "yonder" as opposed to "thither."

Comment: @Brian: Google Books has half-a-dozen instances of [look yonder](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22look+yonder%22&biw=1168&bih=862&sa=X&ei=elkCU7yZCqiM7QaEyoDYDA&ved=0CCEQpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1400%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F1680&tbm=bks) before 1680, but none at all for [look thither](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22look+thither%22&sa=X&ei=yFkCU7TvBefd7Qa97oCgCQ&ved=0CCAQpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1500%2Ccd_max%3A31%2F12%2F1680&tbm=bks) that long ago. I'm no expert on Elizabethan usage, but Google Books does it for me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers but _thither_ **is** a form from that time period.

Comment: @RegDwigнt is the question on topic yet, or is it hopeless?

Comment: @Brian: I've no reason to doubt you. And of course *both* words are archaic/dialectal today, so my gut sense of how I personally use (or *would* use) them may be worthless in terms of assessing how they were used centuries ago. But fwiw, I see *thither* as more associated with ***movement** towards "there"*, whereas *yonder* is just *""there"*. Since your "look" doesn't actually "go" anywhere, to me the natural pairings would be ***go thither*** and ***look yonder***.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13090/discussion-between-brian-j-fink-and-fumblefingers)

Comment: @Brian: Apposite comment! I see we're up to 4 "re-open" votes already (perhaps helped along by our extended discussion here! :)

Comment: @Brian yes, there's no denying it's much better now. Thank you for editing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What happened to the “‑est” and “‑eth” verb suffixes in English?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22459/what-happened-to-the-est-and-eth-verb-suffixes-in-english)

Comment: @Tim this is **not** a duplicate! Related, possibly; duplicate, absolutely not!

Comment: Brian: the answers there are entirely what you are asking for here, which is what 'duplicate' means in these circumstances.

Comment: @Tim: If you read my question, you'll realize that my question is more specific than the other. As a matter of fact, I read that question and posted an answer myself, before I posted my question, unless I am mistaken.

Comment: @Tim, apparently yes, I did answer that question after I asked my own, but I found it before you did, and at no time did I get the impression that my specific question was answered by the more general responses to that question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main problem with the commercial is that the second person indicative/interrogative *lookest/madest thou/endest* is used for all instances of the verb. Ironically, its use is not warranted in any of the times that it is used!

The first sentence should be imperative, the second sentence first person, and the third sentence third person. The irony is that the more correct they would be, the more they would need to change other words to preserve the archaic sound of the speech:

> Trick Number 1: **Look** thou yonder!
>   Haha! I **made thee** to look!
>   So **endeth** the trick!

Answer (score 13):

While *lookest* is a respectable verb form in early modern English, not one of the three instances of the form in your text is appropriate. The form is used only in the second person singular (i.e. with subject *thou*), and not in the imperative.

So the first one would be just *look* (but probably not *over there*. Perhaps *yonder*).

The second one is interesting because at first sight it looks grammatical, since *madest thou* is perfectly good early modern English; but it means "did you make", not "I made you". So *I made thee look* (though, as others have said, probably *I made thee to look*).

The third one should have the third person ending *endeth*, not *endest*.

Answer (score 3):

Up through the Early Modern English that the commercial is botching, personal pronouns were:

- I (first person singular)
- thou (second person singular)
- he, she, it (third person singular)
- we (first person plural)
- you/ye (second person plural)
- they (third person plural)

Like other European languages, English speakers took to brown-nosing by addressing higher-ups with the plural "you" (or a phrase with some form of it, e.g. Spanish usted from "vuestra merced", "y'all's grace"), and now "thou" is pretty much gone save for Quakers' "plain speech", the King James Bible, and Renfairs or historical movies. For regular present tense, it's

I [verb], Thou [verb]est, He/She/It [verb]eth, We [verb], You/Ye [verb], They [verb]

In past tense, the "-est" is still around, but again *only* for second person singular:

Thou [verb]edst

"-est" isn't used in imperatives (commands); nobody would say "Lookest over there". (English of the time still kept the three-way division of locations that, for example, Spanish and Japanese still have: "here", near the speaker; "there", near the listener, and "yonder", away from both. That's why it should be "Look yonder" or "Look thou yonder".)

A lot of people trying to, to borrow someone's term, write or speak "forsoothly" take the "eth" or "est" suffix they maybe sort of halfway remember from a movie or a sermon or exposure to Shakespeare in junior high and tack it onto every verb in sight. Examples in advertising (like this Geico ad) abound... though if you want far worse abuse of the language, there's a Progressive insurance ad that is utterly cringeworthy.

BTW, shouldn't it be "Trick the first" instead of "Trick number one"?